# Transparent pattern tiling in Image Magick generates broken pattern

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to generate image with background and pattern like in [this image](https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/286350544356425419/CB65DF28E998144402A1657313C1030C42BA9589/).

Currently I have this command

```
magick convert \
    \( \
        -size 512x512 \
        -define "gradient:vector=0,0 0,720" "gradient:#5DA2C2-#C70AA0" \
    \) \
    \( \
        -size 4x4 xc:white -alpha transparent \
        -channel alpha -fx "(1-min(1,(j+1)%2)) * 0.1" \
        -write mpr:lines1 +delete -size 512x512 tile:mpr:lines1 \
    \) -composite \
    \( \
        -size 4x4 xc:white -alpha transparent \
        -channel alpha -fx "(1-min(1,j%4)) * 0.25" \
        -write mpr:lines2 +delete -size 512x512 tile:mpr:lines2 \
    \) -composite \
    wallpaper.png
```

which yields [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljf7B.png). You may see that pattern is [broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWICT.png) (especially at the bottom).

If I set pattern size to 64x64 the problem is gone but that's not a real fix.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix that without changing the pattern size?

### UPD:

Full `magick --version` (`convert --version`) output:

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-23 Q16 x86_64 2019-01-04 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenCL OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo fontconfig freetype gslib heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png ps raw rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

> Do the lines always appear at the same places from run to run

Yes, for each of the same set of arguments result is the same (but may vary for slightly different sets of arguments like changing resolution or removing write commands from braces).

> Just as a test, try saving to TIFF rather than PNG. Does that works 
>   or not?

Changing the output format always produces exactly the same result. I tried tiff, gif, jpeg. (With jpeg those lines are a bit blurred obviously, but result looks pretty much the same). This also applies to fmw42's command variant.

> Do you have OpenMP installed with ImageMagick. Also disable OpenCL and see if that helps.

OpenMP is not installed but supported by the IM version I have. 
Disabling OpenCL via environment variable `MAGICK_OCL_DEVICE=OFF` does not change the result. Recompiled IM with and without OpenCL and OpenMP from tag=7.0.8-23 and from master - all the same...

> Are you seeing something in tmp4.png that is not visible to me?

Yes, I still can see that rainbow-colored line on white background if I do `magick tmp4.png -alpha remove tmp4-opaque.png`

Comment: Works fine on my machine. Are you maybe using an 8-bit version? Try `identify -version` and look for `Q8/Q16`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell It says "ImageMagick 7.0.8-23 Q16 x86_64 2019-01-04"

Comment: Try doing the first (gradient) part on its own and saving as `1.png`. Then run a second command and generate the first transparency image as `2.png`. Then run a third command and generate the second transparency image as `3.png`. Then inspect them individually. Finally run `magick 1.png 2.png -composite 3.png -composite result.png` and see what gives.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, yes that yields a correct image. But I still can't understand what goes wrong when I use the brackets. 

By the way imagemagick still can generate an unbroken image if I remove one of the two patterns. I mean `convert \( ...bg \) \( pattern1 or pattern 2 \) -composite output.png`

Comment: You could maybe try adding `+channel` after each `-fx "..."` and/or adding `-alpha on` after `gradient:xxx`. Or wait till @fmw42 comes online :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your command works fine for me on ImageMagick 7.0.8.23 Q16 Mac OSX with libpng 1.6.35. But in IM 7 use magick, not magick convert and not convert or you will get IM 6 behavior. Check your version of libpng and upgrade if necessary. What is your version and date of ImageMagick and on what platform?

```
magick \
\( \
-size 512x512 \
-define gradient:vector="0,0 0,720" gradient:"#5DA2C2-#C70AA0" +write tmp1.png \
\) \
\( \
-size 4x4 xc:white -alpha transparent +write tmp2.png \
-channel alpha -fx "(1-min(1,(j+1)%2)) * 0.1" +write tmp3.png \
-write mpr:lines1 +delete -size 512x512 tile:mpr:lines1 +write tmp4.png  \
\) -composite \
\( \
-size 4x4 xc:white -alpha transparent \
-channel alpha -fx "(1-min(1,j%4)) * 0.25" \
-write mpr:lines2 +delete -size 512x512 tile:mpr:lines2 \
\) -composite \
wallpaper.png
```

[image]

Check this and see if it has your same issue. But I do not see any broken lines.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm using Arch Linux with IM 7.0.8.23-1 2019-01-04 and libpng 1.6.36-1

After I read your answer I removed "convert" from my command and now it works kind of... The interesing part is that your exact command produces even greater distortions for me (see [here](https://i.imgur.com/eGvpxzM.png)). If I remove the trailing +write-s from braces it works ...unless I try to generate an image with a greater size like 1920x1080. The problem occurs at "tmp4.png" stage. For 5000x5000 it works though.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the tmp images. That was for my review. Do you have OpenMP installed with ImageMagick. You might try disabling with a recompile. On some Linux systems that might help. Also disable OpenCL and see if that helps. Also try downgrading or upgrading (if available) libpng and see if that helps. There have been reports of mysterious lines in output and that is being fixed for the next release, I believe. Do the lines always appear at the same places from run to run? Just as a test, try saving to TIFF rather than PNG. Does that works or not?

Comment: CONTINUED: tmp4.png is virtually transparent. I have to remove the alpha channel to see anything. Are you seeing something in tmp4.png that is not visible to me? What do you get from `convert -version`. I want to see all the details. Add that back in your original post. It works fine for me at 1920x1080 size. Still no artifacts.

Comment: @fmw42 Check the details I added to the original post, please :)

Comment: Sorry, I am running out of ideas. I do not have any other good suggestions. It could be a bad disk drive. But I suspect it is something odd in your environment or install. Can you try the same command on a different OS or different computer running the same software? Do you have enough room in /tmp? Do you have enough resources? `convert -list resource`. You could try posting your issue to the ImageMagick Discourse server Developers forum. https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/ Perhaps some one there might have other suggestions.

Comment: @fmw42 I tried everything you mentioned and everything is ok. Tried that command on three different PCs with different hardware (one of them was manjaro linux with iM 7.0.8-14, not arch) and results are still the same. Okay, I will post it to the forum a bit later. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Try Mark Setchell's suggestion of adding +channel after each -fx operation. You use -channel a, but never re-enable the other channels. Also add -compose over before each -composite.